# Storage access framework FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I have managed to open a directory with Storage Access Framework. The SAF returns `Uri` to the opened directory. When I try to open a file inside that directory I get `FileNotFoundException` even through that the file does exists (I have checked).

Obviously I am doing something wrong. This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode != SELECT_FILE_REQUEST || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    if(data == null) return;

    //get uri
    Uri uri = data.getData(); // uri returnded form Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
    File file = new File(uri.getPath(), "text.txt");

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("error", e.toString()); //java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tree/primary:test/text.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, where, in the documentation, you had read that uri returned from this API is a path to a file?

Comment: what makes you think the uri returned is a File uri? more importantly, why didn't you check what the content of the uri is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP can't be bothered to do any amount of debugging before asking the question

Comment: `The file does exist, I have checked` really? there is a file `/tree/primary:test/text.txt` on your device?

Comment: It is an example. I know it is not the correct way. I just do not know hot to get to the uri of a subfile.

Comment: @Selvin: "The SAF returns Uri to the opened directory." Maybe I have treated it as a path, but that's just because I do not know what else to do. And if you are all so embarrassed by my code, why doesn't anyone know how to write It corectly. I would be very grateful. I am struggling with this since morning.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to open a file inside that directory I get FileNotFoundException even through that the file does exists (I have checked)

It is not returning to you a directory. It is returning to you a `content://` `Uri` that you can use with methods [like `fromTreeUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#fromTreeUri%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29).

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to get an Uri to the any subfile inside returned Uri?

Comment: @miXo: I have not played with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` yet. However, `fromTreeUri()` will give you a `DocumentFile` at the root of the tree, and `DocumentFile` has `listFiles()` to traverse downward in the tree.

Comment: I have managed to do that.  However this is not good enough for me. I need to get to the file in constant time. Tnx for help anyway.

Comment: @miXo: "I need to get to the file in constant time" -- I have no idea what that means. Also, there is no requirement that there actually be a file. The user can use the Storage Access Framework to access any provider that the user wants, many of which will be cloud-based (e.g., Google Drive, Dropbox). Some of those will elect to stream the contents down in real time -- that is up to them.